# Start Another Batch File Only Once

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am new to scripting and i am experiencing an issue that i can solve by my own.

I have a script that runs couple of times ( 3-10 ). I need a loop at the end of the script to run another batch file that will send mail that script run okay.

Problem is that it always sends between 3-10 mails ( because script runs mupltiple times)

I need a loop at the end of the script that says Run batch file only once, no matter how many times does main script runs

I have used this:

```
FOR %%A IN (1) DO (
START C:\dodavka\send_mail.bat
)
```

This did not work.

Comment: The best solution would depend if you need to send information about each time it ran, say in a single log file for the day.  A question is: how will the script tell if it has finished running for the day? Is a file created, or a specific file deleted at the end of the day?

Answer (score 0):

Set an environment variable in your sub script code on which you check during the run of this batch file if it is set.

You have to call the batchfile with the CALL keyword so that the values set in that batch-file are kept in memory.

In your main code:

```
If "%MYVARIABLE%" == "" THEN   CALL SUBBATCHFILE
```

In your child code:

```
SET MYVARIABLE = "SET"
```

Comment: Or you can use parenthesis with your `IF` statement, and set the variable from the same script, rather than from the child script. This is safer, as you don't depend on some other batch file's result.